# lambda func exception ,that maybe is .Net Framework 's bug?

Tags: c#, lambda

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new TestImpl();
        Console.WriteLine(t.Test(TestEnum.Value));
    }
}

public class AbstractTest<T> where T:new()
{
    public virtual T TestBase(TestEnum v)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
     Value
}
public class TestImpl : AbstractTest<Product>
{
    public int Test(TestEnum ev)
    {
        Func<int> f = () =>
        {
            var result = base.TestBase(ev);
            return result.Id;
        };
        return f();
    }
}
```

Hi All:

I have a issue like the code (run on the .net4.0).

it will throw exception:An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

if make " var result = base.TestBase(ev);" chanage to " var result = this.TestBase(ev);"
this will normal.
if not use lambda func ,use common func like this:

```
 public class TestImpl : AbstractTest<Product>
{
    public int Test(TestEnum ev)
    {
        Func<int> f = () =>
        {
            //var result = base.TestBase(ev);
           // return result.Id;
            return TestResult(ev);
        };
        return f();
    }

    private int TestResult(TestEnum ev)
    {
        var result = base.TestBase(ev);
        return result.Id;
    }
}
```

that is ok.  i think is "base" or "this" point to different case or other .

Who can tell me why and what's happened? what's the theory?
thanks.

Comment: I've got Visual Studio 2013 RC and I can run your code without problems (except that default(T) will return null resulting I a NullReferenceException on the following line)

Comment: Without testing it I confirm your suspicions. As lambda functions are actually methods in anonymous class, 'base' in lambda function can be incorrectly interpreted as 'base' of this invisible-anonymous class; 'this' is a variable so gets passed to lambda as variables do. Although I ran it without problems with LINQPad against .NET 4.0 and it worked fine (not counting result being null in "result.Id")

Comment: What **exact** .NET version (4.0what?) and compiler version is this? It wouldn't amaze me if this was a bug at one point - if it *was* (and I can't say for sure without detail), it seems to be fixed in "current"

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski: That's not correct in the general case. The compiler is clever enough to not let that happen. `base` inside a lambda returns to the base class of the class in which the lambda is created.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes, but it is still a static call against a virtual method of another type - a pretty subtle combination that is usually explicitly blocked by the CLI. It honestly wouldn't amaze me if this didn't work properly at some point in time. Compiler bugs happen, and CLI bugs happen.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: quick tested it with LINQPad, and you are right. I've edited original comment.

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski And a quick test of the code of the OP by me in LINQPad actually reproduced the problem he is having.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Did you test the OPs code with .NET 4.5?

Comment: thanks all. i run my code on the visual studio 2010 . my system is win2008R2 x64 . i modify my code let the TestBase return new T() that maybe this comment is right:
"Without testing it I confirm your suspicions. As lambda functions are actually methods in anonymous class, 'base' in lambda function can be incorrectly interpreted as 'base' of this invisible-anonymous class; 'this' is a variable so gets passed to lambda as variables do. Although I ran it without problems with LINQPad against .NET 4.0 and it worked fine"@Milosz Krajewski

Comment: @MarcGravell "that is usually explicitly blocked by the CLI" Not from the assembly that defines the type whose base class method is getting called. I use this only where necessary, but one of the places where it's necessary is frequently used in my code, and I haven't had any reports of it not working.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get normally is a result of a 64 bit application trying to load a 32 bit assembly or vice versa.

However, I could actually reproduce the problem on a machine without .NET 4.5 installed.

The generated IL of the anonymous class seems to be really invalid, because ILSpy even fails to decompile it.

Comment: meh; I wouldn't rule it out in this case - would need to test on a specific compiler and .NET version (specific sub-version), but it wouldn't actually amaze me if this was a bug in one version - in particular, as Milosz notes, this would be a static call on a virtual method of another type, which is something that requires special handling to work

Comment: @MarcGravell: I actually just reproduced that error by copy / pasting the code from the OP into LINQPad on a machine without .NET 4.5 installed.